# Content Version image link doesn't work on public Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, contentversion, images

I am using **Content Version** to store images to display them on my Visualforce pages background like :

```
background : url('{image-link}') center center/cover
```

To do so, I retrieve the image links via `MyContentVersion.getVersionDataUrl()` and its something like this:

**https://{domain-name}.file.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/{content-version-id}**

This link format works on the Visualforce page under the Salesforce Org (when I open the page as Salesforce user), however, when I open the same Visualforce page under a public site as guest user, image doesn't display *(or only displays if I log in to the Salesforce org in one tab and open the public site Visualforce page as guest user in other tab in the same browser)* but I want images to appear in all cases.

Is there anything to do to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.